# Android change package name

Tags: android

Is it possible tou change the project name of an apk outside android studio?
i need a tool if exists, to change the com.example.app into com.myapp.app but without any IDE, only with the signed apk file. Is it possible?

Comment: Why would you need such thing? Yes you can decompile and resign, but AFAIK nothing exists to do such thing because such thing should not be needed and could allow people to re-upload existing applications as theirs...

Comment: I need it because my pc crashed....i have the project backup and of course the signed apk which i want to upload it to google store. So i need to install android studio in a new pc to change pagkage name. So, i search if there is an alternative approach..

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, probably for the reasons I just exposed. Re-install Android Studio and rebuild from source, it's not that hard nor long.

Comment: You would need to follow steps to decompile and recompile, like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370326/decompile-an-apk-modify-it-and-then-recompile-it

Comment: Ok. I asked this question in order to get rid of installing android studio in a new pc due to my crashed pc...

Comment: If you have the source though that is by far the most pain free solution.

Comment: This is off-topic, but in a new android studio instalation in a new pc, do i have to create enviroment variables for sdk and java?

Comment: You need to download/install both sdk and java, and no you don't need to set any environment variables. Just add the path to jre/jdk in your PATH system variable

Answer (score 0):

Try to type packageName com.my.name in build gradle.