# Recompile WhatsApp APK file

Tags: android, apk, decompiling, recompile

Recompilation process resulted in errors even when I didn't change the Source code which I got after decompiling the WhatsApp APK.

What's the reason for the errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The decompilation process isn't perfect and the code you get won't mirror the original code 100%. Things like variable names, loop structures and anonymous inner classes might be interpreted differently and not compile correctly unless manually adjusted.

Source: [Decompile Android](http://www.decompileandroid.com/faq/)

For more information take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12370973/2305521) SO answer about recompiling or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6081365/2305521) about decompiling.