# Reverse Engineering of an APK

Tags: java, android, security, reverse

For my master thesis I'm studying and improving the security of an application. The code is obfuscated and my goal now is to see how easily I can exploit the application. However, I'm having some problems; I think I may have found a piece of code that, when removed, will allow me to override some fundamental step of the application logic. As such, I want to recompile the single class that contains that piece of code and replace the one on the application with this new version. I used dex2jar to obtain a jar with all the classes and have already obtained the .java file with the class I want to alter. My exact problem is how I can recompile the file. I already downloaded the Android API jars and I'm using javac with the classpath pointing to the jar having the remaining classes of the application and to the Android API, but I still can't compile as javac complains about some Android literals being ambiguous. Can you please help? Thanks!

Comment: This question is quite ambiguous. What kind of help are you expecting?

Comment: Possible solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370326/decompile-an-apk-modify-it-and-then-recompile-it. You might be missing android manifest and the ressources files.

Comment: Thanks @toshkinl, I'm still new to StackOverflow and didn't search properly! That link seems amazing, I'll take a look at it!