# Recompile a apk file

Tags: java, android, apk, apktool, dex2jar

I was tried to Recompile an app file (apk).

I decompile the apk file with apktool (2.3.1), and dex2jar(2.0), now I have .java file (from the dex2jar), and I don't know how to recompile it,

apktool error:

```
W: Unknown file type, ignoring: (files).java
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar question has already been answered: [Decompile an APK, modify it and then recompile it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370326/decompile-an-apk-modify-it-and-then-recompile-it)

To summarize, you must create a new Eclipse or AndroidStudio project containing your decompiled java source files and compile the project to get a new apk file that can be installed on your android device.