# How do i work with .smali files to easily understand and modify Codes?

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, decompiler, apktool

I am using **APK Easy Tool** to Decompile games and apps in android but it generates .smali files which are difficult for me to understand. I do not have much knowledge about .smili code.

Is there any other way to decompile and edit such android games and apps using .java / kotline / c# etc code same as build before? Please help get ride of .smali code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decompile an APK, modify it and then recompile it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370326/decompile-an-apk-modify-it-and-then-recompile-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.smali` files are essentially an assembly reprensentation of the bytecode (Dalvik bytecode) running in Android apps. It can be, indeed, quite hard to read.

You can use an open source tool called [JADX](https://github.com/skylot/jadx) which will convert this bytecode into `.java` files. It works with `.apk` and `.dex` files.

If you don't want to install this software, you can also use an online [APK decompiler](https://apkdecompiler.net) which also uses JADX to decompile the APK files.

However, I don't know of any program that converts Dalvik bytecode in other languages such as C# or Kotlin.